# wiris plugin is working in tinymce on equation save

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using wiris plugin to enter equation. However, when i save the editor and refresh the page the equation is replaced with plain text. Anyone else having this issue? any other equation plugin for tiniMCE?

Answer (score 1):

Please review the installation instructions at http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/tinymce. Are you using the plugin in any specific CMS? Please note that we have specific instructions for some CMS like Joomla or Wordpress. In any case, we believe that you have skipped step 5 of the documentation. WIRIS formulas, from plugin version 3.50.x, are stored in the database as MathML. You need to include WIRISplugin.js, as detailed on step 5 of the general TinyMCE plugin documentation, in order to convert MathML to formula images. You can check more details at http://www.wiris.com/en/plugins/docs/full-mathml-mode.

Comment: Would you please specify the place where the following line should be added? <script src="<your-plugin>/integration/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image"></script>

Comment: You need to include that line before the head closing tag (`</head>`) of your pages.

Comment: @WIRISMATHsupportteam I'm facing the same problem, I'm using TinyMCE version 5 in an Angular application. I've added <script src="<your-plugin>/integration/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image"></script> also. But it didn't work.

Comment: Either replace the placeholder <your-plugin> by the actual location of your plugin instance, or use src="https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image"

Comment: I am currently using angular 8, and by using npm to download @tinymce/tinymce-angular and tinymce ,  and by putting the tiny_mce_wiris from a zip file called java-tiny_mce_wiris into the node_modules/tinymce/plugins, I somehow able to get the tinymce with wiris up.  However, I programmatically take the data (which contains wiris equation) which i type in the first tinymce, and put it into a second tinymce editor (on the same page as the first one), somehow my equation is replaced with plain text.
where shouldi specify the <script src="<your-plugin>/integration/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image">

Comment: For Angular 8, I add  <script src="https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image"></script> in the index.html.  Its working only if i put the following

  <p><strong>ds</strong><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msqrt><mn>111</mn></msqrt></math>sdsd</p>

in the index.html. But if i am to put it in a nested component, it does not work any more